# jQuery Mobile anchor tags cause Chrome to open dialog

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

jquery mobile makes liberal use of anchor tags:

```
<li><a href='#'>hello world</a></li>
```

But in chrome on android if you tap hold an anchor it pops up with a dialog

```
Open in new tab
Open in incognito tab
Copy link address
Save Link
```

and it makes very little sense to the user because the list item looks nothing like an href. Is there any way to prevent such dialogs from popping up in a jQuery mobile app?

Comment: Have you tried `$('li a').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });`?

Comment: i dont know what event to use. its not touchstart. its not touchend. maybe jqm taphold even though thats not a real event.

Comment: You want to use linked listview or without links?

Comment: just a regular listivew. see here http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/#&ui-state=dialog the li's always have an anchor as a child element.

Comment: It's not necessary to have an anchor. Check the first listview in the demo http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/#list-ul . If you want the style of linked listview, you can add a `span` as a child and add JQM classes.

Comment: ah, it is in the first one. add the classes manually? which classes? that seems a little hacky.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37479/discussion-between-omar-and-user1873073)